# Split observable array and display vertically in a table

Tags: knockout.js, split, html-table

I have an observable with a comma seperated string. What I want to do is to split the observable and bind it so that it's viewed vertically in the table. My view is as below:

```html
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dataOne">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name1"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>  
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

View model is:

```
var data1 = [{
    name1: "one,two"
}];

var viewModel = {
    dataOne: ko.observableArray(data1)     
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

For the moment to simplify things I have used a `foreach` binding to give you a demo. In my code I am using a `with` binding. The reason to use `with` binding is because it represents a single row selected by user.

So how to split the observable and show resulting items vertically in the table, much like this?

```
one
two
```

Is it possible to use code this way?

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="with: dataOne">
    <tr foreach: splittedArray> 
        <td data-bind="text: name1"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is I really don't know how to split it. Please let me know if you need more input.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/111/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to achieve the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
self.name1split = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.name1.split(",");
});
```

And then have the View iterate:

```html
<td>
    <!-- ko foreach: name1split -->
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span><br />
    <!-- /ko -->
</td>
```

See [this fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFw7F/) for a demo.

Note that you need [proper scoping for the `this` keyword](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing_this), possibly needing to save it in a variable such as `self` in your actual application.

Comment: If i use With binding for dataone obs array then nothing is displayed http://jsfiddle.net/rFw7F/1/

Comment: Okay, but did you try to debug that problem yourself yet? Seems there's errors in the console for your fiddle. You should really restructure your view models, perhaps use constructor functions. Please read the bits from my final link.